# Unwanted cloning behavior with jQuery.detach() when trying to move a form

Tags: jquery

I want to move a form's position on a Woo Commerce product page, depending on the screen size.

When the mobile break point is detected, I want to move the form above another element to make it closer to the top of the mobile screen.

When I use

```
let detached = jQuery(form).detach();
```

The form will be removed as expected, however when I reattach to the page using

```
jQuery(detached).insertBefore(description);
```

I get duplicate forms.

Here is the full relevant code:

```js
"use strict";

let productPage = {
  mobileBreakpoint: 768,
  lastKnownSize: 0,
  init: function() {
    this.lastKnownSize = jQuery(window).width();
    this.applyCssFixes();

    if (this.lastKnownSize <= this.mobileBreakpoint) {
      this.onMobileView();
    }

    jQuery(window).on('resize', () => {
      this.onResize();
    });
  },
  getAddToCartElement: function() {
    return jQuery('.product form.cart');
  },
  getDescriptionElement: function() {
    return jQuery('.summary .woocommerce-product-details__short-description');
  },
  applyCssFixes: function() {},
  onMobileView: function() {
    let form = this.getAddToCartElement();
    let description = this.getDescriptionElement();

    // Detach form from page    
    try {
      console.log('moving form');
      // jQuery(form).detach().insertBefore(description);
      let detached = jQuery(form).detach();
      jQuery(detached).insertBefore(description);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  },
  onDesktopView: function() {
    let form = this.getAddToCartElement();
    let description = this.getDescriptionElement();

    // Detach form from page        
    // jQuery(form).remove();

    // Insert above description
    // jQuery(form).detach().insertAfter(description);
  },
  onResize: function() {
    let currentWidth = jQuery(window).width();

    // Desktop screen size
    if (this.lastKnownSize <= this.mobileBreakpoint && currentWidth > this.mobileBreakpoint) {
      this.onDesktopView();
    }
    // Mobile view
    else if (this.lastKnownSize > this.mobileBreakpoint && currentWidth <= this.mobileBreakpoint) {
      this.onMobileView();
    }

    this.lastKnownSize = currentWidth;
  }
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  productPage.init();
});
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Can you reduce this to a [mcve]? Preferable a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Side note (it's not the problem): `detached` already refers to a jQuery object, so don't call `$()` again.